# Using Excel to to Return unique values for Identical lookup values

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am attempting to use VLookup to match a "Purchase Number" to a specific "Invoice Number". To accomplish this, I have several identifiers about the purchase that I put together to come up with a special "Concat ID". I then have a list of Invoice Numbers that also has the same list of identifiers to create the same "Concat ID'.

The problem I am running into is that the set of identifiers is not unique (aka a purchase of 10 Computers might happen multiple times a year, therefore it is in my list multiple times). Because of this, when I use Vlookup to match the 2 IDs, it always is giving me the same Purchase Number for each time the Concat ID is found (which is just the first occurrence of that Concat ID).

Since there is no other data that would allow for matching (because Invoice date and purchase date are not always the same date or even close to one another), I am just wanting to ensure that each Invoice Number has a unique purchase number.

I'm not sure if its possible, but I was hoping I would be able to perform the vlookup then just skip to the next time the Concat ID is found, allowing for no duplicates, but that hasn't been feasible for me. Because this is a file of 16000 rows, any insight is very appreciated.

I'm sure that's not the clearest explanation, so I've attached a screenshot of the 2 examples in case anyone has any insight. I've been using a simple VLookup, but I'm open to trying VBA or any other suggestions everyone has. As always, thank you Stack community in advance for any help/insight!

#### Purchase Info

[image: Purchase Info]

#### Attempted Matchup with Invoice Info

[image: Attempted Matchup with Invoice Info]

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?  You already have a list of purchases.  And they all have a unique purchase number by design.  Why not use the purchase number?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks for your reply. I am attempting to match up the invoice number (a column i regretfully left off the sheet) to the purchase number. The issue I have is that the same purchase number is put on multiple invoices, because of the same Concat ID

Comment: Go back one step. Why do you need this `Concat ID` to determine the purchase number?  What will you be able to do with the `Concat ID` that cannot be done by querying the original table -- either with a complex formula, or by using simple or advanced filters, pivot table, or a Power Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you expect to do with the ConcatID purchase number, but to return the purchase numbers that match your specific ConcatID, generated in the manner you describe in your question, and "skipping to the next" in the case of identical ConcatID's, you can do something like the following;

- Note that I made a Table out of your original data, and am using structured references.  This allows a much smaller amount of data to be processed compared with referencing the entire column, and will also autoadjust the range as you add/remove rows
- Also note that if your Table starts in other than Row 1, you will need to make an adjustment in the formula to account for that.

---

```
G2: =INDEX(PurchaseTbl[#All],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/1/(PurchaseTbl[Concat ID]=F2)*ROW(PurchaseTbl),COUNTIF($F$1:F2,F2)),7)
```

and fill down as far as needed

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've got a really dorky solution, but maybe it will help.

Use this formula to create a unique ID for each row. It will count how many times the specific `Concat ID` has been used previously in the table, then append it to the end. You can use the `Concat ID Unique` in your `VLookup` to get the correct `Purchase Number`.

`=D2 & "_" & (COUNTIF(D$1:D1, "=" & D2))`

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help! I'll try this and let you know how it works for me!